# Trying to find a faster route other than using Formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So right now I have a macro that is pulling data from another workbook using a formula.  I was wondering if there was a faster way to have it process the data. Because there are time in which I have large data set and it takes longer and longer for it to process or if this is the fastest way and there is no way around it. Here is what I'm using to pull the information:

```
With Range("V2:V" & LastDataRow)
    .Formula = "=IF(A2 = ""No Specific Program"",IF(F2 = """",""No PIN"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(B2,F2),'\\NW\Data\Tech\Team\Data\DataMining\[PIN_TABLE.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$I,4,FALSE),""NO GAD DATA"")),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,F2),'\\NW\Data\Tech\Team\Data\DataMining\[PIN_TABLE.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C:$I,4,FALSE),""NO GAD DATA""))"
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = True
End With
```

Also I have ScreenUpdating to False, Calculation to Manual, disabled status bar, and EnableEvents to False.

Comment: Open the external workbook, read the values into an array and process using the array.

Comment: Jeeped's comment is the best solution - but also be aware that `=INDEX(MATCH())` is more efficient than `=VLOOKUP` over large data sets as you're not referencing multiple columns that aren't required.

Comment: The two methods I employ are what @Jeeped said, or query the info with ADO. Depends on the particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to breakdown the code with If then and ELSEIF statements -

```
for each y in rng 

If sheet("Name").range("A2") = "No Specific Program" AND sheet("Name").range("A2") = "" then' the A2 here can be controlled with "A" &   y.row
sheet(y.address) = "No PIN"

Else if sheet("Name").range("A2").value & sheet("Name").range("A2").value = "something" then....
sheet(y.address) = "No PIN"
end if
next y
```

Still I would recommend INDEX(Match(value,array,0),Match(value,array,0)) if there is only one value, else I would use a sumif/sumifs. Or just Match. All depends how the data is structured.